# How to perform web-auth in locust?

Tags: python, authentication, locust

I am looking at the [Locust Documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html) and one of the flag in configuration is

```
 --web-auth WEB_AUTH   Turn on Basic Auth for the web interface. Should be
                        supplied in the following format: username:password
```

I looked into it's github repo to find out how to use this feature, and the relevant section in [locust/main.py](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/78381c9410eb711837a55b909919aa9946553aab/locust/main.py#L286-L294) has the following code

```py
web_ui = environment.create_web_ui(
                host=web_host,
                port=options.web_port,
                auth_credentials=options.web_auth,
                tls_cert=options.tls_cert,
                tls_key=options.tls_key,
                stats_csv_writer=stats_csv_writer,
                delayed_start=True,
            )
```

I also looked at the [pull request](https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/1313) that enabled this flag. In the [tests](https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/1313/files#diff-c3c09c105a3c62bbf2d88cca4162b8a6c8c2b19880e5f8a67e03a06251e50287R258-R285), I see that hardcoded user id/password is passed in.

This has not given me a good idea on how to use web authentication in locust because I expected a handler function for web authentication which receives user/password combination that returns `true/false` or `roles` for the combination, but I did not see any such thing.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `--web-auth` parameter for Locust has to do with enabling authentication required to use the Locust web UI, in order to secure the site so not just anyone with access to where you are running Locust from could mess with your test or see the results. The username and password you specify with that would be required when visiting the Locust UI. It's meant to be a quick and easy way of securing it for a single user so it only takes one username and password.

If you're looking for how to use Basic Auth for web requests on your test, [Locust is based on Python Requests](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#control-headers-or-other-things-about-my-http-requests) so something like this should help:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/authentication-using-python-requests/

**EDIT:**
Locust UI isn't really designed for multiple users out of the box. In my experience, the last user who accesses the UI gets a working page and anyone else who had been working before then breaks with weird behavior including inconsistent data or no data. I solved it by setting up an nginx reverse proxy in front of the UI. You could do the same and have nginx perform the authentication instead of Locust itself. Something like this may work:

https://www.tecmint.com/setup-nginx-basic-http-authentication/

Comment: I am looking for restricting access to Locust Web UI for a select group of people. The information about the people and associated credentials could live somewhere else (file, db). So, I am looking for authentication mechanism on locust web ui. The app I am testing already has access mechanisms. My goal is to provide access Locust Web UI to selected users. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Edited my answer with info about nginx reverse proxy, which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I am considering this option right now